# React - input value to generate a number not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to learn React and have gotten stuck trying to have an input take in a number then pass that number when the button submit is hit.  Most of this works (below) however when I hit submit, my number is converted to a string and I don't know what.  Any help or guidance here would help, thank you

```
    import React from 'react';
import Stars from './star'

class StarMaker extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numStars: 200,
    }
  }
  setNumStars(num) {
    console.log(typeof num);
    const numPulses  = [...Array(num).keys()];
    console.log(numPulses);
    this.pulses = numPulses.map(i => this.generatePulse(i));
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setNumStars(this.state.numStars)
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.setState({
      numStars: Number(e.target.value)
    })
  }

  getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  generatePulse(i) {
    const props = {
      key: i,
      top: this.getRandomNumber(-385, 556),
      left: this.getRandomNumber(1, 2430),
      scale: `scale(${this.getRandomNumber(1, 2)})`,

    }
    return (<Stars {...props} />)
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const numPulses  = [...Array(this.state.numStars).keys()];
    this.pulses = numPulses.map(i => this.generatePulse(i));
  }
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return (
      <div>
        {this.pulses}
        <input value={this.state.numStars} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} type="number"></input>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StarMaker;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` value in HTML will always be a `string`, no matter what `type` will you specify. Having said that, whenever you need to use a `number` data type instead of `string`, you have to cast it explicitly, basically by parsing the numeric value from the string:

```
parseInt(this.state.numStars, 10);
```

Comment: so that would go in like so, right? `  handleClick() {
    this.setNumStars(parseInt(this.state.numStars, 10))
  }`

Comment: it's very close to working.  I enter in the number and hit submit, nothing happens until I enter in another number (into the text area) and then the previous number populates.

So if I type in 100 and hit submit, nothing.  But then if I type in 20, then 100 populates.  (and so on)

Comment: I assume you base your observations on visible `this.pulse` elements. Right now the pulse elements will always be one render behind the registered value, the easiest way to solve it would be calling `this.forceUpdate()` at the end of `setNumStarts` method.